# Evento $()click do Ajax não funciona

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

Estou com um problema no evento `$().click()` do Ajax.

Estou tentando enviar uma tabela HTML para converter em JSON e assim enviar para o PHP. Porém, quando clico no botão para pegar o evento, não acontece nada. Nem no console ocorre um erro. A tabela é o seguinte:

```
<table id="tabela">
<thead></thead>
    <tr class="corpo">
        <td colspan="4"><input type="text" class = "headerInput" value="Disciplina: GCC209 - Programação WEB"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="corpo">
        <td colspan="4"><input type="text" class = "headerInput" value="Docente Principal: RAMOM GOMES COSTA"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="corpo">
        <td colspan="4"><input type="text" class = "headerInput" value="Docente Responsável: RAMOM GOMES COSTA"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="corpo">
        <td colspan="4"><input type="text" class = "headerInput" value="Turma: 10A     Versão do Plano: 1ª"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="corpo">
        <td colspan="4"><input type="text" class = "headerInput" value="Carga Horária Teórica: 0     Carga Horária Prática: 68"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="corpo">
        <td colspan="4"><input type="text" class = "headerInput" value="Atividades Avaliativas: Prova 1: 20%; Prova 2: 20%; Exercícios: 20%; Seminários: 20%; Trabalho Final: 20%"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="corpo">
        <td colspan="4"><input type="text" class = "headerInput" value="Estratégia..."></td>
    </tr>
    <colgroup span="4">
        <tr>
            <th class="Dia1">Dia</th>
            <th class="Data1">Data</th>
            <th class="Descricao1">Descrição</th>
            <th class="Dia1"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="lastLine"></td>
            <td class="lastLine"></td>
            <td class="lastLine"></td>
            <td class="lastLine"></td>
        </tr>
    </colgroup>
</table>

<div class="adiciona">
    <button class="botao" onclick="start()">Adicionar</button>
    <button class="botao" id="converter-tabela">Salvar</button>
</div>
```

E o meu script está da seguinte maneira:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/table-to-json@0.13.0/lib/jquery.tabletojson.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#converter-tabela').click( function(){
        //alert("chegou!");    
        var table = $('#tabela').tableToJSON();
        console.log(table);
        alert(JSON.stringify(table)); 
        // Você envia os dados para o PHP utilizando AJAX
        $.ajax({
            // Enviamos os dados da tabela para um script PHP
            url: 'teste.php'
            , data: { dados_tabela: table }
            , method: 'POST'
        }).then(function(result) {
        // No retorno, apenas confirmamos
            if (result.success) {
                alert('Enviado para o servidor com sucesso!');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: O teu código jQuery está antes do HTML certo? muda para o final do `body`

Comment: Sergio, deu certo. Porém, tenho uma dúvida. Estou preenchendo esta tabela via JavaScript. Quando chega na linha alert(JSON.stringify(table)); apenas aparece a tabela com vazio. O que posso fazer? Desculpe, sou inexperiente.

Comment: E o `console.log(table);` funciona?

Comment: Sim, porém com array todo vazio. Mas retorna com a quantidade certa de linhas.

Comment: Isso é problema do plugin. Tens um link para a documentação?

Comment: Está dizendo em realação ao Ajax e/ou JSON? Se sim, estes são os links : 
(Ajax) https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js


JSON( https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/table-to-json@0.13.0/lib/jquery.tabletojson.min.js)

Comment: A formatação da tua tabela não está correta. Não tens `tbody` e o `thead` está vazio.

Comment: Entendi, acredita que se eu formatar a tabela de forma correta, eu conseguiria pegar os dados de forma correta?

Comment: Sim e não, a tua tabela tem `input`s, isso muda um bocado as coisas. A documentação mostra exemplos de como usar uma função para extrair dados: https://github.com/lightswitch05/table-to-json#options se não conseguires faz uma pergunta à parte para te ajudar-mos

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que a primeira linha desse código vai procurar `$('#converter-tabela')` que ainda não foi lido pelo browser.

O browser precisa de ler o HTML primeiro, ou então tens de ter uma função que só corra quando a página der o sinal (evento) de que está pronta.

Podes fazer a segunda alternativa com:

```
$(function(){
   // o código aqui dentro correrá quando a página tiver carregado
   $('#converter-tabela')...
   // ...etc
});
```